# Retrieve Schema for MySQL DB-Connection does not work in Talend

Tags: mysql, talend

I've created a new MySQL DB Connection, and verified it's OK by pressing the **Check** button in **DataBase Connection - Step 2/2** form.

Then I right-click on the DataBase Connection I created and select **Retrieve Schemas**.

On the first screen of the Schema form that is opened I leave all default values and press **Next**.

On the second page the Next button is greyed-out, and no matter what I select/fill on the form it remains being greyed out.

Anybody knows why it may be so?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the last step ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, but you can avoid it.
If you select the CATALOG, the Next button will still be greyed as on attached screenshot.  [image] But if yo will expand the CATALOG and Sellect All, the Next button will be active.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't expand it. Even though the connection is OK, and the schema exists.

Comment: have you solved it? because i'm trying to create the same problem.

Comment: Yes, thanks, it was some schema problems. When I use other schema, everything is fine. Probably permissions or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, in order to resolve it I needed to generate database diagrams and then verify that talend could see all the tables I was looking to retrieve. Basically if you cannot expand any schemas it means there is nothing to import.
[image]

Comment: This helped me because I checked schema name. My Source database had different schema and not 'dbo'.